# Example of large sites running on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Can anyone give examples of large sites running on Google App Engine at the moment?

If you can please give rough estimate of traffic and how long it has been live for.

And any significant periods of downtime if any.

Thanks
Ron

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/customers/

Answer (score 11):

Wolfire Games [posted a rather glowing review](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-app-engine-served-humble-indie.html) of their experience using App Engine to serve the Humble Bundle. They served 3.4 million pageviews over 12 days.

Jaiku [runs on App Engine](http://jaikido.blogspot.com/2009/03/jaiku-is-now-served-from-app-engine.html).

They [posted case studies](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2008/10/app-engine-case-studies.html) a while back for BuddyPoke, Pixverse and Hyperic.

[Earth Hour](http://www.earthhour.org/home/) runs on App Engine and apparently [served 450 hits per second](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/05/web2py-support-new-datastore-backend.html) during the event.

TweetDeck uses App Engine  for [sending mail and serving recommendations](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/04/tweetdeck-and-google-app-engine-match.html#links).

The White House uses Google Moderator, which runs on App Engine, for [Open for Questions](http://www.whitehouse.gov/openforquestions). They may run on a different set of servers, though.

As for downtime, all scheduled and unscheduled outages are documented on the [App Engine Downtime Notify](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-downtime-notify/topics) group.