# Google App Engine Examples

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Example of large sites running on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266783/example-of-large-sites-running-on-google-app-engine)

Hi,
   I would like to know whether there is great potential in learning to use Google App engine. Can some experts tell me what are the more famous game/ applications buit on the Google app engine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that many Google products like Gmail and Google Docs use App Engine.  It might not be the exact same version that they offer to the public, but these are exactly the kind of massively scalable apps that App Engine is designed for, so it would be strange if they didn't use a similar API internally.  I would expect that the API was developed for their own apps first and then released to the public later, like Google Web Toolkit was.  But this is all speculation.

BigTable is part of App Engine and that has been confirmed by Google to be used in many of their own products.